# Myql - querying data in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, codeigniter

I have a listing page with some filters. The data reside in three different tables with some common field like date, title, etc. My problem is how to get data from three table and list this data on a single page. This page must implement pagination and basic filters. I am come with this solution:

Query the table separately and combine and mix the result using php (Codeigniter). In fronted I'm using AngularJs.

I am looking for a guideline not an implementation. I can implement this my own way but I want a better solution that work in a great way.

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: What about [mysql JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) ?

Comment: No, because these three table contains feeds of three medias like facebook,twitter, youtube. I can't do anything with JOIN.

Comment: I just planned how to do this and not written any code so far.

Comment: You need to learn about JOIN feature in MySQL
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Ok, Let me check

Answer (score -1):

LET'S TAKE AN EXAMPLE

table1  having field user_id(primery key) , name , email
and 
table2  having field detail_id , user_id(foreign key) , address ,pincode

by this way you will get common data which is present in both table 

`SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.user_id= table2.user_id`